# c++ launch new process and terminate existing one

Tags: c++, terminate

I want to be able to have an updater application launch the new version of the application, then terminate itself.

When I try the 'usual' of calling the new application via 'system', the updater never exits.

Thoughts?

Comment: What OS? Do you need a portable solution?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows or [exec](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdln_exec.htm) on Unix. Use macros to create a wrapper over the OS specific code.

Comment: Uh, how about use regular functions or even a polymorphic interface?

Answer (score 0):

exec family of functions replaces current process with a new one. If not called from child after fork, this should replace your program with new one.

system calls fork and then executes shell in a child and waits for its return, that's why your updater does not exit.

See man 3 exec and man 3 system.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something along the lines of CreateProcess on Windows that creates and runs a separate process. The `system` call will wait for whatever command you entered to finish and then return.